# how to get resource id when creating listfragment

Tags: android

I have this class:

```
public class list extends ListFragment {

    String[] countries = new String[] {
            "India",
            "Pakistan",
            "Sri Lanka",
            "China",
            "Bangladesh",
            "Nepal",
            "Afghanistan",
            "North Korea",
            "South Korea",
            "Japan"
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,countries);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context="com.FoodOrderApp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
android:padding="0dp">

<TabHost
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="0dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/all_dishes"
                    android:name="com.FoodOrderApp.list"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/tab2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/fav_dishes"
                    android:name="com.FoodOrderApp.list"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

and I want to get id of current list fragment in onCreateView method

Comment: What id are you talking about? id for listfragment???.

Comment: pls have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html.

Comment: Yes, i have two lists with different id and same class, i want to output different data to them, so i need to identificate them somehow..

Comment: "i have two lists with different id and same class". I don't understanf

Comment: I think he wants to initialize 2 listviews from the activity, thus displaying them both on the same layiut.

Comment: @Aashir i see only listfragment no activity in the post.

Comment: I meant to say ListFragment*, sorry.

Comment: @Aashir then i don't see the point of using listfragmnet

Comment: I have added xml info. Is my way of doing stuff is incorrect? How should I do it then? Two different classes?

Comment: @Raghunandan you're right but considering the updated question, I'd say it wasn't phrased proplery. And Rokas, seeing as you're adding tabs to your layout, you can have have separate fragments for them and then have a listener which will switch layout and initiate that specific fragment. Consider taking a look at this tutorial. http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-fragment-tabs-in-android/

Comment: Whats the point of different tabfragments, if im going to add one list per tab?

sorry for my poor knoweledge, I have just started dev'ing android..

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
ListView lV = getListView();
```

To get the id of the current list, which by the way is `android.R.id.list` in a **ListFragment** or a **ListActivity**, if you were to do it manually.